# How to modify a html select to display all options with matching data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html select drop-down listing various cats, each with a data attribute of "color", an associated color, and a button next to the drop-down.

Using pure javascript, I want to be able to click the button, get the "color" attribute of the selected cat, and have the list display all cats with the same color attribute.
Example: I've selected Cat 1 who has a color attribute of "black", I click the button and the drop down displays Cats 1, 3 and 4 as options.

Would I need to implement a for loop, or would for/in statement work?

```js
function filter() {
  //onclick modifies the "catList" select to display all cats with the same data-color attribute.
  var list = document.getElementByID("catList");

};
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="catList">
      <option data-color="black">Cat 1</option>
      <option data-color="orange">Cat 2</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 3</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 4</option>
      <option data-color="orange">Cat 5</option>
   </select>
</form>

<button type="button" id="btn" class="menu" onclick="filter()">Filter Cats</button>
```

Comment: Please try posting some code that we can comment on. To get you started you need to read the color attribute of the selected option, then loop over all options and apply a display:none style to the ones that don't match your discovered color.

Comment: @JamesGaunt that will work, but it will make the other options disappear, and the user cannot select them. unless there's unfilter button.

Comment: I thought he wanted that to happen "Example: I've selected Cat 1 who has a color attribute of "black", I click the button and the drop down displays Cats 1, 3 and 4 as options.". But if something else is supposed to happen - then yes - something else needs to be done.

Comment: Start with `options = list.options;`. You can get the selected option with `options[list.selectedIndex]`. Then you can loop over `options`, testing their data against the data from the selected option.

Comment: @JamesGaunt I'll try putting code to comment on in my future comments. I had a rough idea of how to implement and thought my question was sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the option list, and add display none, to options that don't have the same data attribute value as with the selected option.

**Option 1** (this will hide the other options, and you won't be able to select them, until you refresh the page)

```js
function filter() {
  //onclick modifies the "catList" select to display all cats with the same data-color attribute.
  var list = document.getElementById("catList");
  var option = list.options[list.selectedIndex]
  list.querySelectorAll('[data-color]').forEach(function (element) {
    if (option.getAttribute('data-color') !== element.getAttribute('data-color')) {
        element.classList.add('filter');
    }
  })
};
```

```css
.filter {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="catList">
      <option data-color="black">Cat 1</option>
      <option data-color="orange">Cat 2</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 3</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 4</option>
      <option data-color="orange">Cat 5</option>
   </select>
</form>

<button type="button" id="btn" class="menu" onclick="filter()">Filter Cats</button>
```

**Option 2**

```js
function filter() {
  //onclick modifies the "catList" select to display all cats with the same data-color attribute.
  var list = document.getElementById("catList");
  var color_filter = document.getElementById("color");
  var value = color_filter.options[color_filter.selectedIndex].value;
  list.querySelectorAll('[data-color]').forEach(function (element) {
    if (value !== element.getAttribute('data-color')) {
        element.classList.add('filter');
    }else {
        element.classList.remove('filter');
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.filter {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<select id="color" onchange="filter()">
      <option value="">Select filter</option>
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<select id="catList">
      <option data-color="black">Cat 1</option>
      <option data-color="orange">Cat 2</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 3</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 4</option>
      <option data-color="orange">Cat 5</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: When you down vote please state why?, as this will also help me rectify my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this way

HTML

```
<form>
  <select id="catList">
      <option data-color="black">Cat 1</option>
      <option data-color="orange">Cat 2</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 3</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 4</option>
      <option data-color="orange">Cat 5</option>
      <option data-color="black">Cat 6</option>
   </select>
</form>

<button type="button" id="btn" class="menu" onclick="filter()">Filter Cats</button>
```

JS

```
         window.filter = function () {
            var action_list = document.getElementById("catList");
            var selected_color = action_list.options[action_list.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-color");

            for (var i = action_list.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (action_list.options[i].getAttribute("data-color") != selected_color) {
                    action_list.remove(i);
                }
            } 
        };
```

Solution 1. see live demo here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/u1baumwx/3/)

Solution 2. see live demo here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/u1baumwx/2/)

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, in Options 2, is_selected is an array that holds all cats without the selected color, then it's compared against action_list, and the cats in is_selected are being filtered out of action_list?